# SQL: column <> '%TEST%' does not work, why?

Tags: sql

I do not understand why following code does not work?

```
SELECT [column1], [column2]
FROM table where Column1 <> ('%TEST%')
ORDER BY 1
```

I want to have all rows where Column1 does not contain TEST

Thanks

Comment: your answer is below, but additionally, `ORDER BY 1` will either do nothing much, or it might randomly re-order the rows returned.

Comment: You need to accept an answer!

Answer (score 8):

Use [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator with [Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) %:

```
SELECT [column1], [column2] 
FROM table 
WHERE Column1 NOT LIKE ('%TEST%') 
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use wildcards you have to use the [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator:

```
SELECT [column1], [column2]
FROM table where Column1 NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: My god :D Sure... Sorry for stupid question, I am tired of it today.

Answer (score 2):

[Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) (`%`) in SQL should be used in conjunction with the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT [column1], [column2]
FROM table where Column1 NOT LIKE ('%TEST%')
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT [column1], [column2]
FROM table where Column1 NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

% is a wildcard expression, which is probably the reason why; I think you may, if you want a literal %, wrap it in square braces [%], but I actually forget if that is the answer, and apologize if it isn't.

If you want to use it as where the column doesn't have the text test in it, then you do:

where column1 not like '%Test%'

Comment: You need to say `Column1 NOT LIKE '%TEST%'`. ...and this was supposed to be an answer, not a comment >_>

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear. I really mean % to be used here as wildcard expression. Therefore IMHO it should ignore any row that contain TEST

Answer (score 0):

You need to say Column1 `NOT LIKE '%TEST%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean using like?

`where Column1 not like '%TEST%'`